# how do I take the dot product of these two arrays of different shape?

Tags: python, numpy

```
 xT_dot_x_dot_xT = [[ 0.00000000e+00 -5.06371260e-04 -1.97580457e-03]
 [ 0.00000000e+00 -7.54147768e-04  1.70472264e-03]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  4.02927399e-05  3.20196152e-04]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  8.85248184e-04 -2.95877457e-04]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  2.01046467e-04  2.06828117e-05]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  5.04493713e-04  5.10215759e-04]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  8.46385956e-05 -8.65459442e-05]
 [ 0.00000000e+00  6.81161880e-04 -5.64813614e-04]
 [ 0.00000000e+00 -6.24537468e-04  3.47018242e-04]
 [ 0.00000000e+00 -3.38315964e-04  2.02894211e-04]] 
 y = [[208500]
 [181500]
 [223500]
 [140000]
 [250000]
 [143000]
 [307000]
 [200000]
 [129900]
 [118000]]
```

this data was derrived in roughly this manner:

```
print(x, y)
[[1710 2003]
 [1262 1976]
 [1786 2001]
 [1717 1915]
 [2198 2000]
 [1362 1993]
 [1694 2004]
 [2090 1973]
 [1774 1931]
 [1077 1939]] [[208500]
   [181500]
   [223500]
   [140000]
   [250000]
   [143000]
   [307000]
   [200000]
   [129900]
   [118000]]
zeros = np.zeros((len(x), 1))
x = np.append(zeros, x, axis=1)

#print("values for process\n", x,y)

xT = np.transpose(np.linalg.inv(np.tensordot(x.T, x, axes=([0],[-1]))))
xx = np.tensordot(xT, x.T, axes=([0],[-1]))
print("intermediate\n", xx, y)
# wls = np.tensordot(xx, y, axes=([-1],[0])) # -- failing line
```

I had to work around the multidimensionality of my inputs, but now that I've gotten this far, it seems like the method that got me this far is failing me now.

Comment: You don't: dot product is defined on two vectors of equal length.  Please clarify what you intend as a result.

Comment: @Prune I guess I've done this wrong -- what does equal length mean? They are both 10 rows long.

Comment: [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html)

Comment: I gather that you want the dot product of `y` with each column of `x`?  That's not how `tensordot` works.  The two must have the same quantity of dimensions, and you need to specify the axes properly.  See the examples.

Comment: okay, so I have to .. problably at the start, split x into 3 distinct arrays and do this to each separately. @Prune thank you.

Comment: Perhaps more easily, replicate `y` to have the same shape as `x`.

Comment: y is always just the size of one column of x

Comment: Tell us the shape of the two arrays, and which axes you want to sum.

Comment: its in the OP already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your `x` is (10,2) and `y` is (10,1):

The tensordot produces a (10,10), and is the same as switched `dot` (matrix product):

```
np.tensordot(x.T,x, axes=[[0],[-1]])
np.dot(x,x.T) 
x@x.T
np.einsum('ij,kj',x,x)
```

That is the summation is on the smaller, size 2 dimension.

`xT` and `xx` are also (10,10)

```
np.tensordot(xx,y, axes=[[-1],[0]])
np.dot(x1,y)
```

produces a (10,1), having combined a (10,10) with (10,1) on the last and 2nd to the last axes.

---

Oops, I missed the:

```
x = np.append(np.zeros((10,1),int),x, axis=1)
```

which makes a (10,3) array.  But tensordot with `x.T` still sums on the smaller dimension, producing a (10,10).

---

Oops, further correction, I missed a detail in the `xx` calc.

```
 xT (10,10)
 xx (10,10) with (10,3) => (10,3)
```

Now

```
np.tensordot(xx,y, axes=[[-1],[0]])
```

is problematic because it seeks to combine (10,3) and (10,1) on the 3 and 10 dimensions.

```
np.dot(xx,y)
ValueError: shapes (10,3) and (10,1) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 10 (dim 0)
```

You could sum on the two 10's, producing a (3,1) array.  Is that what you want?

```
np.dot(x.T,y)     # (3,10) with (10,1) => (3,1)
```

Comment: it is. I apologize I _thought_ that I wanted a (10,1) array but I want a (3,1) array .. your answer mirrors what I have implemented on my own by now. thank you

Answer (score 1):

The input arrays (also known as vectors or matrices) have to have the same dimensions, not the same length.  For example, the following will work fine:

```
xa = np.array([[2,3,4,5], [1,2,4,3], [2,3,2]])
ya = np.array([[1], [2], [9]])
np.dot(xa, ya)
```

You might want to examine why you need a dot product - depending on how you are interpreting the data, you will likely need to add two dimensions to your array "y" populated with ones.  Assuming the values are along the y axis, it might be padded like:

```
 y = [[1, 208500, 1],
 [1, 181500, 1]] #and so on for the remaining rows
```

Again, you would just need to ensure which axis your values belong to.

Comment: they don't have to have the same shape when using tensordot, though